# bootstrap collapsed menu, does not open on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar

Alright, so I have read through a bunch of threads about this, not of which helped me fix the paramount problem I am facing. The thing is I have built a bootstrap menu, the most basic one following an example from getbootstrap.com. I honestly do not understand at this point what I had done wrong and followed the suggestion that I should load my jQuery.js before I loaded the bootstrap.js. [Here is a link to a jsfiddle of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/5xqf14aa/)

Here you have the full code I used for the page I am currently trying make function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WITHELD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script rel="javascript" style="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script rel="javascript" style="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/style.css">
  <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ext/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="ext/img/head.jpg" style="max-height:100px;">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
    </div><!--/.row/ Head-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle group -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapsemen" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect Nav links, forms and other content. -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemen">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-hashpopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blacktion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seperated</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="boop!"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div><!--/.Container-fluid/ Content wrapper.-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xqf14aa/2/)
you forgot to add `#` to data-target attribute.

**working code snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Din Socialjurist</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script rel="javascript" style="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script rel="javascript" style="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/style.css">
  <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ext/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="ext/img/head.jpg" style="max-height:100px;">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
    </div><!--/.row/ Head-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle group -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsemen" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect Nav links, forms and other content. -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemen">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-hashpopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blacktion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seperated</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="boop!"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div><!--/.Container-fluid/ Content wrapper.-->
</body>
</html>
```